# How to find index of node

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am searching for a smart way to find the string index of all `<p>` tags in an  HTML document to calculate the distance between them.

---

I want to calculate the amount of HTML code needed to describe the space between `<p>` paragraphs. After that I want to extract the `<p>` tags with the shortest distance to others.

My current solution is:

```
require 'nokogiri'
htmlString = '<html> <p>mhh</p> <p>test</p> </html>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(htmlString)
result = []
doc.xpath('//p').each do |node|
  i = htmlString.index(node.to_s) #This is not a smart way!
  result.push(i)
end
p result # =>[7, 18]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The distance? In characters? Why? If you want to extract/change things,  the parser itself is the tool you want. This has the aroma of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It's difficult to explain. Short said: I want to calculate the amount of html code needed to describe the space between <p> paragraphs. After that I want to extract the <p> tags with the shortest distance to others.

Comment: The space between paragraphs? On screen? HTML doesn't make that easy because there's the rendered display of the basic markup, and there's the display of the rendered markup after CSS and JavaScript have had their say. The two usually don't resemble each other for many different reasons.

Comment: Please don't use "edit" or "update" tags in your text. Instead put the changes in-line where they would have gone in the first place. We can see what, when, and where things were changed if we need to.